# Xamarin Forms prevent iOS clearing previous entry text after focus

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms I tried to add show password feature to entry. so I toggled isPassword(true/false).
user has to click on the eye icon to see the password and it means that entry will lose focus.
Now, In iOs if user touches entry to enter more character or delete some. iOs will clear the entry and user has to enter again.
Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 1):

We can Custom **[EntryRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry)** to avoid that . Such as creating a **CustomEntryRenderer** in **project.iOS** solution :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.iOS
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer,IUITextFieldDelegate
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control.SecureTextEntry)
            {
               Control.Delegate = new MyTextFiledDelegate();
            }
            
        }

    }

    internal class MyTextFiledDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate
    {
        public override bool ShouldChangeCharacters(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
        {
            //return base.ShouldChangeCharacters(textField, range, replacementString);
            string updatedString = textField.Text.Substring(0, (int)range.Location)+replacementString+textField.Text.Substring((int)(range.Location+range.Length));
            textField.Text = updatedString;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Used in **Xaml** :

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="20">
    <Entry Text="First Entry" IsPassword="True"/>
    <Entry Placeholder="Second Entry"/>
</StackLayout>
```

The effect :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is formerly correct, however due to this bug: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2619

You instead have to do it like this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace AppEntryTest.iOS
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer,IUITextFieldDelegate
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control.SecureTextEntry)
            {
               Control.ShouldChangeCharacters += Control_ShouldChangeCharacters;
            }
        }

        private static bool Control_ShouldChangeCharacters(UITextField textField, NSRange range, string replacementString)
        {
            string updatedString = textField.Text.Substring(0, (int)range.Location)+replacementString+textField.Text.Substring((int)(range.Location+range.Length));
            textField.Text = updatedString;
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Otherwise when the page containing the Secure field disappears, it will crash.